# Charcter wrapping in Delphi 7 with Chinese pictogram string

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-7

I am trying to enhance a Delphi 7 application that wraps text to fit in a box.

The original code appended words from the source until the line became too long, then printed the line minus the overflow word, and continued on starting with the overflow word.

While working with a Chinese translation, we ran encountered source text that had no  characters on which to break.  That is, we would get one huge chunk of pictograms.

We decided to append pictograms from the source until the line became too long.  The problem is that the simple character-oriented approach that worked with regular ASCII text is failing with this unicode text, because we do not know how many bytes to consider for each of the unicode characters (pictograms).

Is there an easy way to assign the Chinese string to a "unicode string" and then grab each unicode "character" out of the string?  I'm sure this is fairly simple, but my head spins between strings, wide strings, long strings, etc.

I assume that I will have to use the facilities in the Jedi VCL library.  I have looked at the code, but there are no examples, and the Help is so old that it no longer works.

Comment: "I'm sure this is fairly simple." Don't be so sure. It's about as hard as it gets. And you've got the wrong tool. Ironic that your question is tagged delphi-7 and Unicode, two tags that really don't mix well.

Comment: I understand your point, but I am still left having to solve this problem with the tools at hand.

Comment: In full generality you need a Unicode library like ICU. It's still not very clear where your data comes from. How are you dealing with the international text at the moment? Surely you are not using ANSI encoded text.

Comment: Good question. We use GnuGetText, which appears to perform a UTF8 encoding internally.  At the moment, we are just passing this through.  The naive approach to word wrapping appeared to be working OK in French.  In fact, if we embed enough <space> characters in the Chinese, the original code wraps reasonably well.

Comment: How are you displaying text? What encoding does your code use? Utf8?

Comment: We are cramming the UTF-8 into legacy code, which appears to be working.  But I honestly do not know exactly how/why this is so.  All I want to do is be able to take an 8 pictograph string (which might be encoded as 16 or 24 bytes) and pick the byte doublets or triplets out that represent each pictograph.

Comment: Unicode is much more complex than that

Comment: There is no mechanism for accessing a single visible entity (pictograph) using unicode?

Comment: Is there a tutorial that explains UTF8, WideStrings, Encoding, Decoding, Unicode, etc, especially in Delphi 7 terms?  So much of what is out there presumes that one us using more up-to-date software